# Visibility of Web Apps

Tags: commcare

Say your domain has multiple apps. When you log into CommCare HQ as a mobile user, and navigate to the Web Apps section, what determines the subset of apps that are visible as web apps to the particular mobile user?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are two things that determine which mobile workers can see which Web Apps in their project in CommCare HQ.

First, for an application show up in Web Apps at all for any user, it must be configured to be a "Web App" on its app settings page. (Link looks like: https://www.commcarehq.org/a/YOUR_PROJECT/apps/view/YOUR_APP_ID/)

Second, the project administrator can make certain Web Apps visible only to users in certain groups by going to Users > Web Apps Permissions and selecting "Customize each mobile worker's access to Web Apps". There you can pick up to one group of users that will have access to that Web App. (Link looks like: https://www.commcarehq.org/a/YOUR_PROJECT/settings/cloudcare/app/)